# How to convert .flv video into .h264 format with FFmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264

I want to convert from `.flv` to `.h264` format.

Problem: I did a conversion from FLV to H264 format but my converted video (.h264) is running so fast (just like we'd click on a fast forward button).

I used the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i example.flv -sameq -vcodec libx264 -vpre default -ar 22050 output.h264
```

Comment: Please update your question to include the complete console output. Do not use `-sameq`: [sameq does not mean "same quality"](http://superuser.com/a/478550/110524). FFmpeg usage questions are better suited for superuser.com.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution is that you need a container format. Raw h.264 does not have any timing information for a video which is why your player is playing it very fast.

Also your command is all messed up. Do you want audio in your output or not? If yes then you need to specify a container format which will have both audio and video.

Either change your output to a mp4

```
ffmpeg -i input_file -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline out.mp4
```

or some other container. If you want a video only stream remove the audio options and add `-an`.

If you want to use AAC audio instead of whatever the FLV file has:

```
ffmpeg -i input_file -c:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 128k -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline out.mp4
```

If your ffmpeg does not have the `-c` or `-profile` options, update to a more recent version.

Comment: `-vpre` does not exist on any recent FFmpeg version and should be avoided. Use `-profile:v` to specify profiles and `-preset slow` etc. for encoding presets.

Comment: @av501  following command is working fine to produce mp4 video with h.264 format but the audio is not working in IPhone (its working in Android mobiles)  ffmpeg -i example.flv -r 25 -sameq -ab 128kb -vcodec libx264 -vpre default -s 320x240 -b 768kb -ar 44100 -acodec copy output.mp4        and when i used acodec = aac , ffmpeg show me following message "encoder 'aac' is experimental and might produce bad results.
Add '-strict experimental' if you want to use it."

Comment: @slhck when i used -preset slow  i got following message in ffmpeg "Unrecognized option 'preset'"

Comment: @ShishirMudliyar Make sure you run the latest version of FFmpeg or at least something newer than 0.9. `vpre` has been deprecated for quite some time now – several hundreds of bugs have been fixed since your version.

Comment: @ShishirMudliyar I added another example with AAC audio, which you will probably need when targeting iPhone/Android devices. But maybe you could make your question more clear and tell us what exactly you want to do (i.e. which devices) and what the input file actually contains.

Comment: @slhck My all input files are .flv type ( video audio both) and i need to convert this flv into h.264 formate so that we can run that video into Iphone/Android.

Comment: @ShishirMudliyar, to run on iphone/android you still need to put it in a mp4. They do not play raw h.264 files. H.264 is a codec for the video which forms an elementary stream inside the mp4 container. To get the files playing in android/ios depending on set of devices you are targeting you may also want to set bitrate resolution and frame rate to control the level and the profile with ref frames = 1 for constraned baseline if you want a single file to play across devices. Else seperately encode for subsets which can play main profile & higher quality files.Read up a bit on codecs/containers

Comment: @ShishirMudliyar Please do us a favor and include the full uncut command line output from FFmpeg in your question. This is absolutely important for any FFmpeg question, also those you might ask in the future. Also check out [What are the differences between H.264 Profiles?](http://superuser.com/questions/489087/what-are-the-differences-between-h-264-profiles/489092#489092) and [What is a Codec (e.g. DivX?), and how does it differ from a File Format (e.g. MPG)?](http://superuser.com/questions/300897/what-is-a-codec-e-g-divx-and-how-does-it-differ-from-a-file-format-e-g-mp/300997#300997)

Comment: @slhck Now following cmd is creating video which is running good in Android/Iphone for video ,audio both ffmpeg -i example.flv -r 25 -sameq -b:a 128k -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -s 320x240 -b:v 768k -ar 44100 -acodec aac -strict -2 output.mp4  ..... i upgrade my ffmpeg to 0.10 ....really thanks for your valuable support

Comment: @av501 Now following cmd is creating video which is running good in Android/Iphone for video ,audio both ffmpeg -i example.flv -r 25 -sameq -b:a 128k -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -s 320x240 -b:v 768k -ar 44100 -acodec aac -strict -2 output.mp4 ..... i upgrade my ffmpeg to 0.10 ....really thanks for your valuable support

Comment: @ShishirMudliyar You're welcome. Feel free to accept av501's answer by clicking the green checkmark next to it! But **please** don't use the `sameq` option. It [doesn't do what you want](http://superuser.com/a/478550/110524), it doesn't even exist anymore in FFmpeg 1.0. And next time you ask a question about FFmpeg, please ask it on [SU], and include the full command line output, not just the command you're using. Thanks!

Comment: @slhck i got this Unrecognized option 'c:v' error how can i fix this?

Comment: @Pus Use a recent version of FFmpeg. If yours does not have the option it's quite outdated. You can build it yourself or download a static build from their homepage.

Answer (score -2):

The magic key word you are looking for is "frames per second".

Add and " -r 30" for 30 fps in the output video for example.

Sebastian

Comment: I was getting error  pts after filters MISSING
No pts value from demuxer to use for frame!,?% 0 0                                                                                                           
pts after filters MISSING
No pts value from demuxer to use for frame!,?% 0 0                                                                                                           
pts after filters MISSING
No pts value from demuxer to use for frame!,?% 0 0

Comment: I used -r 30 in my command :: ffmpeg -i example.flv -r 30 -sameq -vcodec libx264 -vpre default -ar 22050 output.h264 but the result wouldn't change , video still running fast forward

Comment: This will never work since the `.h264` raw format does not contain any information about how many frames per second are stored.

Comment: However the resulting .mp4 must have some kind of frame rate?

Comment: Well, there is no "resulting MP4" file if you output the raw h.264 bitstream to a `h264` file. A `h264` file only contains the video data, nothing else. You would need two wrap it in a container like MP4 in order to specify how many frames per second should be shown. (By the way, don't forget to notify other users with `@slhck`, otherwise they don't get a reply)

Comment: @slhck thanks for the advice, I was reading your ffmpeg command with the resulting .mp4 file instead of the initial one :)